# Delta Lake Time Travel Separate Tables

Tags: apache-spark, delta-lake

In Apache Spark Delta Lake, is it possible to set different backup windows for different tables? I want some parts of the system to be saved forever and others to be saved not at all or for only a week.

Comment: What do you mean by backup? Keeping the history of changes? If yes, how often tables are updated?

Comment: Yes, backup = history. Tables are updated frequently, perhaps tens of thousands of times per day. Can you set different retention periods for different tables?